# CRTP, forward declarations and templates in cpp files

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, crtp

I'm using the CRTP pattern to create an interface, which other classes will derive from.

In the interface I forward declare a structure (important because I don't want to drag other stuff in the interface), but I include its definition in the cpp file which defines the interface.

**Interface.h**

```
#ifndef INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
#define INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED

// forward declaration
class ForwardDecl;

template <class Derived>
class Interface
{
public:
    ForwardDecl interfaceMethod();

};

#endif // INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
```

**ForwardDecl.h**

```
#ifndef FORWARDDECL_H_INCLUDED
#define FORWARDDECL_H_INCLUDED

struct ForwardDecl
{
    ForwardDecl(int i):internal(i)
    {}

    int internal;
};

#endif // FORWARDDECL_H_INCLUDED
```

**Interface.cpp**

```
#include "Interface.h"
#include "ForwardDecl.h"

template<class Derived>
ForwardDecl Interface<Derived>::interfaceMethod()
{
    return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->implementation_func();
}
```

And this is the implementation which implements the interface

**Implementation.h**

```
#ifndef IMPLEMENTATION_H_INCLUDED
#define IMPLEMENTATION_H_INCLUDED
#include "Interface.h"
class ForwardDecl;

class Implementation: public Interface<Implementation>
{
    friend class Interface<Implementation>;
private:
    ForwardDecl implementation_func();

};


#endif // IMPLEMENTATION_H_INCLUDED
```

**Implementation.cpp**

```
#include "Implementation.h"
#include "ForwardDecl.h"
#include <iostream>
struct ForwardDecl Implementation::implementation_func()
{
    ForwardDecl fd(42);
    std::cout << fd.internal << std::endl;

    return fd;
}
```

And the main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Implementation.h"
#include "ForwardDecl.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Implementation impl;

    ForwardDecl fd = impl.interfaceMethod();
    cout << fd.internal << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get linking errors on both VS and GCC.

Any workaround? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: making forward declaration work in the interface is the main point here, if it weren't for that I'd move everything to the header file.

Comment: What you're trying to do (if I understand it, which is iffy) may be possible with a template *interface* definition and pointers, but instance-level like this I'm having a hard time seeing it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a flaw in your very approach: You have a public function returning a ForwardDecl instance, so every client wanting to use this function also must include the according definition of that type, which implies you can make that type public from the beginning. This includes making the function definition inline, which will fix your linker problems.

However, if you really want to hide the content of that structure and you are sure clients don't need it directly, you can declare it and then pass around references to such a structure (or pointers, but raw pointers are evil albeit not in the same league of evil as #macros). In that case, I would still make the function definition inline.

If you really, really want to not make the function inline, you can also explicitly instantiate the function template for the types that you need. You would add at the end of the template's .cpp file something like `template class Interface<int>;` (I don't remember the exact syntax so take that with a few flakes of fleur de sel, check out the [C++ FAQ at parashift.com for more info](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-types)). This makes the template a little less universal though, as it requires adjustments for any type that you want to use it with, but it can be an approach in some corner cases.

Comment: yup fixed it a while ago after reading the FAQ on parashift, since your answer was correct, you get the points :)

Answer (score 1):

The definitions of function templates and member functions of class templates need to be visible in all translation units that instantiate those templates. That is, you shouldn't put template definitions in a `.cpp` file, which means you need to move the contents of `Interface.cpp` up into `Interface.h`.

Comment: Yes but if I do that I have to #include "ForwardDecl.h" and **this** is what I'm trying to avoid.